# In nodejs on windows, how do I use the `uid` option with child_process.spawn?

Tags: node.js, spawn

What I would like to do is to get the current users uid. I am exec'ing a process elevated and then I want to spawn another process with the original users uid again.

How do I get the current users uid on windows?

```
var child = spawn(process, args, {
    detached: true,
    uid: uid, // how do I get this on windows?
    cwd: appDir,
    stdio: [ 'ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe']
})
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_getuid
 Note: this function is only available on POSIX platforms (i.e. not Windows)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`process.getuid()` (SO requires at least 30 chars)

Comment: This is the answer but on windows `getuid()` is undefined, which means that uid's in general are not supported on windows.

There appears to be limited to no support for impersonation in windows. The [runas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/runas) can help you with elevation at least. It is a native addon however. There is no good way to do it presently without a native addon as far as I can tell.